# Constructions "as good as", "as weak as", etc

Tags: meaning, comparison, emphasis

I'm not quite familiar with the constructions "as good as...", "as weak as..." as they are used below.

> The fact that the metanotation of derivability made every bit *as good as a claim as* material implication to be an explication of implication seems to have been overlooked by believers and unbelievers alike.
>
> *As weak as* the grounds for introducing the new operator may seem to have been, its translation into modal terms returned modal notions to logic [...].

What do these constructions mean? Could you restate those sentences in different words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example sentences are good, because "as [x] as" can be used a lot of ways, for many [x].

> The fact that the metanotation of derivability made every bit as good as a claim as material implication to be an explication of implication seems to have been overlooked by believers and unbelievers alike.

The metanotation of derivability made a good claim, at least of equal merit to the claim made by material implication, for being an explication of implication. But based on the discussion about it, nobody seems to have noticed.

For something simpler but similar,

> John made as good as a promise to be here.

John didn't actually promise to be here, but I'm as confident that he will be here as if he had promised.

While we're on this topic, another one that's a bit complicated.

> I've been having a good week so far. Maybe this is as good as it gets?

This means, "This week has been better than I'm used to, but it falls really short of what I expected, given the amount of effort I and possibly others have gone through to get me to this point. Were my expectations too high?"

---

> As weak as the grounds for introducing the new operator may seem to have been, its translation into modal terms returned modal notions to logic [...].

Despite the very weak grounds for introducing the new operator may have seemed to have been, its translation into modal terms returned modal notions to logic [...].

Generally, when you have, "As weak as [object possibly with descriptors] may seem to have been, ...", the gist of the sentence will be something like, "this thing sounded like a bad idea but it turned out to be a good one."

Answer (score 0):

**As weak as:**

"as weak as", simply means, something is very weak, even up-to (the next word)

**As good as:**

"as good as", simply means, something is very good, even up-to (the next word)

**Examples:**

> His as good as you.
>
> His as weak as you.